# Cartoon (Anime?) - Boy turns into some kind of monster when he fights. When he kills the enemies, they turn into some kind of balls and he eats them

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

I was really young when I watched this cartoon - anime. I think I was 5 or 6 years old. The story pretty much is summed up in the title. I watched it before 2006 for sure.

This boy was like hooked on these nut-like balls, and one girl won't let him eat them. Thing is, he can turn into some kind of monster when he gets angry. And his enemies, when killed, turn into those balls. So they let him eat them to go back to normal.

Comment: Been searching for this too! I am pretty sure I found out the title maybe 5 years ago but I totally forgot. It was aired in my country, Philippines, in 2006. The mc has long hair.

Comment: @OrekiHotaro Is the [answer here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/262195/7957), "Betterman", the same anime you were looking for?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you ever found the answer or not, but I've been searching for this anime myself and I'm almost certain we're both looking for the same thing which I found to be *[Betterman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betterman_(TV_series))*

> The year is 2006, a series of seemingly random terrorist attacks rock the globe. Dubbed "Algernon", normal people suffer psychotic breaks and begin murdering everyone around them - often in profoundly disturbing fashion. In the wake of traditional law enforcement's failure to turn up any link between these incidents, a private contractor known as Akamatsu Industries is brought in to explore if Algernon is a disease, an unknown terrorist group, or even more exotic possibilities.
>
> Meanwhile, a mysterious mass fatal accident occurred while preparing for the opening ceremony at the geofront type underground amusement park "Bottom the World". Asami Toko of the Algernon research institute "Modi Warp" who visited the investigation with the authorities, concluding that the accident was caused by Algernon. Around the same time, high school student Keita Aono accidentally stumbles inside the prototype Neuronoid Kakuseijin 01 in which is piloted by a girl named Hinoki Sai, his childhood friend he hasn't seen in years, and on board the cockpit as a rare "Dual Kind" head diver. In their exploration in the "Bottom the World" in hopes for them to escape, they both find out the mystery behind the Algernon phenomenon and the mysteries surrounding the mysterious man named Lamia who is classified as a "Betterman".

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you describe this a bit, and explain how it matches the question?